Remove folder icons from desktop display in Ubuntu 24.04
The eight folders in the Home folder suddenly appeared on my home display as icons on left edge of the display. I tried the suggested removal procedure:

Right-click anywhere on your home screen to open the context menu and click on the second to last Desktop Icons Settings option.

It will open the Appearance tab from the Settings app, from where you have to toggle off the Show Personal Folder option under the Desktop Icons section.


There is no Show Personal Folder option. What am I missing?

This question is similar to: How to remove/hide personal directories on desktop screen?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Can you append the output of the following command, 'ls -al' and then 'cd Desktop' and repeat 'ls -al' to your original question.

The link provided by graham solved the problem. Desktop is now free from unnecessary clutter. Very much appreciated. Thank you.

Looks like I responded too soon. The desktop reverted back to fully cluttered with icons. No idea why. Quite frustrating.

I don't know if it's still present. I found the option here:
Settings app -> Ubuntu Desktop -> Show Home Folder


It is still present. The OP has done this via the desktop context menu.

I had the same issue. It seems the issue was caused by me deleting the Desktop folder in my home directory. I solved it by recreating the Desktop folder and then logging out and back in.
In my case, since i don't like having useless folders in my home directory, i decided to rename the Desktop folder as ~/.hidden_desktop and to change the corresponding line in ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs to:
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/.hidden_desktop"
And then again, I logged out and logged back in to make sure the change would be taken into account.
